# Function is not showing all expected data when loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the React class below that shows a list of users(zoomers).

Each `zoomer` has a property called `isHidden`.

When the page first loads, I want it to just show zoomers who have the `isHidden = false`.

I made a checkbox control that, when checked, should show all zoomers, including even the hidden ones.

When it's not checked, I don't want it to show any zoomer with `isHidden = true`.

So when I run the web app, and load this React component, it initially shows me no users at all...hidden or not hidden.

And when I click the checkbox, it reloads and just shows me the hidden users.

So it's not really doing what I am want it to do and I'm not sure why.

I was hoping someone could please show me the way.

Here is my code:

```
export default class ZoomerGrid extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        zoomers: List(),
        showHidden: false
    };
  }

    toggleShowHidden = e => {
       const { value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ showHidden: true });
    }

    render() {
    
        let zoomersShowHidden = this.state.zoomers.toJS();
        zoomersShowHidden = zoomersShowHidden.filter(x => x.isHidden = this.state.showHidden);

        return (
            <div>
                Show Hidden Zoomers? <input type="checkbox" name="test" onChange={this.toggleShowHidden} value="false" />
                {zoomersShowHidden.map((zoomer) => <ZoomerTile key={zoomer.id} zoomer={zoomer} />)}
            </div>
        );
   }
}


Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initial state is set to an empty List:

```
this.state = {
    zoomers: List(), <-- This creates an empty Immutable list
    showHidden: false
}
```

So in your render, your zoomersShowHidden will be an empty list. If you want data to show up, you need to load data into your state.

Your toggle is also always setting the showHidden to true and will not toggle back and forth:

```
toggleShowHidden = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ showHidden: true }); <-- This never toggles the value of the checkbox
}
```

Use instead:

```
toggleShowHidden = () => {
    this.setState({ showHidden: !this.state.showHidden });
}
```

Also, your input is not using the state you have stored:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" onChange={this.toggleShowHidden} value="false" /> <-- The value is being set to false all the time
```

Use instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" onChange={this.toggleShowHidden} value={this.state.showHidden} />
```

Based on your comment, your filter would toggle the hidden and non hidden items back and forth. What you want is to show all the items that are not hidden and only include the items that are hidden if showHidden is true.

Use instead:

```
.filter(zoomer => !zoomer.get("isHidden") || this.state.showHidden)
```

This logic will check first if the isHidden value is false. If it is, it returns that object as part of the filter so it will always show the non hidden items. For the next or part, we know that the isHidden is true at this point, so the only logic we need to check to filter and return the result is to check that we want to showHidden, so we can use the showHidden state after the or.

Also, why are you using immutable to store in state and then alter it to a plain javascript object in the render? You can access the properties in the Immutable object without having to convert it to JS.

Here is an example:

```
export default class ZoomerGrid extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        zoomers: Immutable.fromJS([
            {
                id: 1,
                isHidden: false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                isHidden: true
            }
        ]),
        showHidden: false
    };
  }

    toggleShowHidden = () => {
        this.setState({ showHidden: !this.state.showHidden });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Show Hidden Zoomers? <input type="checkbox" name="test" onChange={this.toggleShowHidden} value={this.state.showHidden} />
                {
                    this.state.zoomers
                    .filter(zoomer => !zoomer.get("isHidden") || this.state.showHidden)
                    .map(zoomer => <ZoomerTile key={zoomer.get("id")} zoomer={zoomer} />)}
            </div>
        );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am loading data now at the beginning and that works now only showing zoomers who are not hidden. Thank you but when I click the `checkbox`, it reloads with only zoomers that have `isHidden` set to true. I hope to see all zoomers, true and hidden, not just true.

Comment: I saw that your setting of the showHidden was always setting it to true and you were setting your checkbox to always be false (you were not passing in your showHidden state into the checkbox value). I have updated my answer just recently with everything I noticed and even included information on how to access the Immutable properties without having to change it to a plain Javascript Object

Comment: Based on your comments, I updated the filter. It checks first to see if the value is not hidden (false). If it is not hidden, then it return true right away and returns the value. The next part of the or we know that it is a hidden record, so then we check to see if showHidden is true (which means we want to show this hidden value). That update to the filter in my bottom example code should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`x.isHidden = this.state.showHidden` this is an assignment instead of a comparison, change to `x.isHidden === this.state.showHidden`